# Cartoon that aired somewhere between 2000-2010 similar to Digimon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I was really young so I only remember that in the first episode a group of kids get on a train then suddenly their monster avatars (in which they can transform later) appear for a split second.

The main guy gets his ability to transform first and it is some red monster I think. Then in the second episode I think they encounter in the forest they are in some kind of monster that can make you dream nightmares so it starts implanting them in every singe one of them.

I think the rival of the main kid transforms for the first time into some white cat tiger I think and that's it. I don't remember anything else but it is possibly from Japan(?).

Comment: [Bungo Stray Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bungo_Stray_Dogs)?

Comment: No no this is new I said it is old maybe made in the late 90`s animation style from pokemon or digimon maybe. Still thanks I like this anime gonna start watching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about a spinoff of Digimon called [*Digimon Frontier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Frontier).

In it 5 children are chosen, and sent into the digial world via a "Trailmon". During the first episodes, they have to discover their monsters, during which time 5 opposing warriors begin to hunt the kids.

[image]

Comment: Yep, sounds exactly right.  It's not a spinoff though, it's just the 4th season.  The US dub was aired on a different channel than the first 3 seasons, and several episodes aired out of order, so I can see why it seems like a spinoff.

Comment: And for the final comparison in the question, the boy on the far right is the rival/loner and turns into the light-element wolf digimon above him

Comment: MY GOD YOU ARE RIGHT I GOOGLED IT JUST NOW.THIS FEELING OF NOSTALGIA CAN`T BE DESCRIBED. I have been searching for this since last October. God bless you men, I hope you and the other searching for a cartoon/anime find what they are looking for just as I did here.

Comment: @shadowhunter197 you can always mark the answer as accepted as well.

Comment: I did it thank you so much

Comment: I asked for same anime in 2019.